# Trouble passing a type'd parameter to a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm wanting to guarantee that the single parameter I'm calling a function with is just one of three typed values.  I'm sure I'm not understanding the correct way to do it because I'm getting the error `RateType is not defined`.

I also have this in stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nfwclm

Here is my main method that includes the type exported

```
import sub1 from './sub1';

export type RateType = {
  OffPeak: "OFFPEAK",
  OnPeak: "ONPEAK",
  SuperOffPeak: "SUPEROFFPEAK",
};

sub1(RateType.OnPeak);
```

and here is sub1

```
import { RateType } from './index';

function sub1(rateType: RateType) {
  console.log(`sub1:rateType:${rateType}`);
}

export default sub1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need both a *type* for RateType and an *actual JavaScript object* - so, define the object (with `as const` to avoid widening), then use the object in the main method, and export the type of the object.

But since it looks like you only want the object *values* type, not the *whole object* type, use `keyof` to take the keys from the object as a union, then look them up on the object to get a union of the values. Call the exported union something else to avoid confusion - after all, it's not a RateType mapping of properties to values so much as just a collection of values as a union.

```
import sub1 from './sub1';

const rateType = {
  OffPeak: "OFFPEAK",
  OnPeak: "ONPEAK",
  SuperOffPeak: "SUPEROFFPEAK",
} as const;
type RateType = typeof rateType;
export type RateTypeValues = RateType[keyof RateType];

sub1(rateType.OnPeak);
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do what I'm trying to do here? I feel like I landed on a bad plan.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're using the JavaScript object later in this file. If you're only using it to call `rateType.OnPeak` *once*, then there's no need for the object - instead, call it with plain `'ONPEAK'` and you can export just the type. If you *do* use other properties of the object later, declaring both the object and exporting a type for the object is quite reasonable, I don't find that approach code smelly at all.

Comment: thanks. I do plan on using this type in many places so want to make sure I'm always calling them the same things. It's just new syntax to me so looks odd but if it is what is expected, I'll get use to it.  Just seems like a very common pattern that might have a simpler use somehow.

Comment: I should have tested before commenting. I"m still not getting it.  I updated my stackblitz and still have an error.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xtns2b?file=index.ts

Comment: Oh, you're using `RateType` in the other module as a *union of values*, but you were exporting the type of a plain object. Transform it into a union first if you want to use it as a union.